# How to get nodemon to kill process when a program crashes?

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs, nodemon

Perhaps I'm missing something, since I've never encountered this before, but I'm trying to run a Node/Express/Babel setup with nodemon, and every time there is a crash (almost), nodemon leaves the port in use, so I have to manually kill the process. I'm using Node 11.15.0 and MacOS 10.13.6 and the error I get is

```
events.js:170
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4321
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1259:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1307:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1395:7)
    at listen (/Users/robertanthony/Documents/Projects/sandbox/axa/src/index.js:27:10)
    at $initialConnection.$initialConnection.then (/Users/thisuser/Documents/Projects/sandbox/axa/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:723:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1286:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My `package.json` is

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js}\" --quiet",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-jwt-permissions": "^1.3.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.1",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.6.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "eslint": "^6.2.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2"
  }
}
```

Perhaps it's something I'm doing wrong?  Any help much appreciated --  If it's not obvious what the solution is, is there any way to run babel without nodemon?  I tried 'node --exec' but that didn't work…

Comment: Please see this [thread](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1221)

Comment: @James -- that seems a different issue.  Mine is that nodemon isn't killing the process when it crashes, not in getting it to restart.  Maybe I'm missing something?